# How many ways it can be done?

Tags: probability

> There are $5$ chairs. Bob and Rachel want to sit such that Bob is
>   always left to Rachel. How many ways it can be done ?

I have solved this in the following way:

seats:  * * * * *

1. `B * * * *`  the rest seats can be arranged by $4$ ways
2. `* B * * *`  the rest seats can be arranged by $3$ ways
3. `* * B * *`  the rest seats can be arranged by $2$ ways
4. `* * * B *`  the rest seats can be arranged by $1$ ways

The total is $10$ ways.

Am I rightly done this

Comment: Are you sure you count a proper number of chairs in each case...?

Comment: Your answer is correct. The way you've done your text diagrams is sketchy, but your method is sound.

Comment: Consider the possibility that the 5 chairs are arranged in a circle.

Comment: There are "typos" in the description, but you know what you are doing.  A quicker way is to note that there are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to do the job, or for $n$ chairs where $n\ge 2$, there are $\binom{n}{2}$.

Comment: @Nicolas So if we have  50 chairs  we  the conditions  remain same then the answer will be $\binom{50}{2}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the seats aren't arranged in a circular fashion, yes, your answer is correct. ;)

This is because there are 5 choose 2 ways to arrange the seats, which equals 10.